# Filter input received by getline

Tags: c++, getline

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

string firstFile, secondFile, temp;

ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;

cout << "Enter the name of the input file" << endl;
cin >> firstFile;

cout << "Enter the name of the output file" << endl;
cin >> secondFile;

inFile.open(firstFile.c_str());
outFile.open(secondFile.c_str());

while(inFile.good()) {  

    getline(inFile, temp, ' ');

        if (   temp.substr(0,4) != "-----"
            && temp.substr(0,5) != "HEADER" 
            && temp.substr(0,5) != "SUBID#"
            && temp.substr(0,5) != "REPORT"
            && temp.substr(0,3) != "DATE"
            && temp             != ""
            && temp             != "") 
        {
            outFile << temp;
        }
}

inFile.close();
outFile.close();

return 0;   
}
```

Hi All. I'm attempting to output all lines from a text file that do not meet the criteria in the control structure -- i.e. no blank lines, no symbols, etc. However, when I run this code it outputs everything, not taking into consideration my specifc requirements. If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of, you should not loop `while(inFile.good())`. Instead use `while (getline(...))`.

Comment: Do you want to process lines or words?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at a reference [such as this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) you will see that the second argument to `substr` is *the number of character* not the ending position.

This means that e.g. `temp.substr(0,5)` might return `"HEADE"` which is indeed not equal to `"HEADER"`. This means that all non-empty string will be output.

Also note that right now, you don't actually read *lines* but *words* as you separate the input on space.

Answer (score 0):

When you repeat the same action multiple times, that's a sign you need a function:

```
bool beginsWith( const std::string &test, const std::string &pattern )
{
   if( test.length() < pattern.length() ) return false;
   return test.substr( 0, pattern.length() ) == pattern;
}
```

First of all you can test it separately, then your condition will be much simplier and less error prone:

```
if ( !beginsWith( temp,  "-----" )
      && !beginsWith( temp, "HEADER" )
      && !beginsWith( temp, "SUBID#" )
      && !beginsWith( temp, "REPORT" )
      && !beginsWith( temp, "DATE" )
      && temp != "" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Short version (C++11):

```
const std::vector<std::string>> filter {
    {"-----"}, {"HEADER"}, ... }; // all accepted line patterns here

while(getline(inFile, temp)) {
    for(const auto& s: filter)
        if (s.size() == temp.size() &&
            std::equal(s.begin(), s.end(), temp.begin()))

            outFile << temp;
```